# Validate access to an entity: Customizing authorization validation annotations

Tags: java, spring

There are two entities and two service layers in my Spring boot app: `User` , `Group`

The following `removeMember` method is in the service layer:

```
/*Remove member with id userId from group with id groupId, if username is the admin of that group*/
public void removeMember(long groupId, long userId, String username) {
    Group group = loadById(groupId);
    validateAdminAccessToGroup(group, username);
    User user = userService.loadById(userId);
    validateMemberAccessToGroup(group, user.getName());
    if (group.isAdmin(user)) {
        throw new BadRequestException("Group admin cannot delete himself/herself from the group");
    }
    group.removeMember(user);
}

private void validateAdminAccessToGroup(Group group, String username) {
    User user = userService.loadByName(username);
    if (!group.isAdmin(user)) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException("User with id " + user.getId() + " was denied to access group with id " + group.getId() + " as an admin"); 
    }
}

private void validateMemberAccessToGroup(Group group, String username) {
    User user = userService.loadByName(username);
    if (!group.isMember(user)) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException("User with id " + user.getId() + " was denied to access group with id " + group.getId()); 
    }
}
```

As you can see, only the admin of a group can remove a member from that group.

`validateAdminAccessToGroup` validates that user has access admin access to a group, otherwise it throughs an error. `validateMemberAccessToGroup` validates that user is a member of a group.

Should we do this access check inside the method ? or using @PreAuthorize annotations ? Can we say this is a cross-cutting concern ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it's better to handle `checkAccessToGroup` in `User` model object, not passing neither `User`, `GroupId`, nor `AccessLevel`, just handling it inside the model with these values set as the object member variables.

Then call it on `User` instance in Controller layer. If you called it in Service layer, you would need to call it repeatedly in Service methods when one Controller is utilizing more than one methods in Service, and you would eventually be tightly coupling the Access Checking part with the Service itself, which would decrease the reusability of the Service.

Comment: Then I would need to call `GroupService` (Service provider for Group entity) from `checkAccessToGroup` which resides in User entity, which I guess is not a good idea.

Comment: If that's the case, execute required methods to get the infos from `GroupService` in Controller, then pass these results as params to `checkAccessToGroup()` of `User`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use spring security's PreAuthorize classes. [Here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression) is an small example of the usage. Your code can be called from the PermissionEvaluator implementation, which will be invoked by spring internal classes.

since you need an entity/record based access, you can implement the overriden [hasPermission](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/4.0.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/access/PermissionEvaluator.java#PermissionEvaluator.hasPermission%28org.springframework.security.core.Authentication%2Cjava.io.Serializable%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.Object%29) method which takes the following parameters as input authentication(logged in user details), targetId(groupId), targetType(group), permission(delete).

You need to have the below annotation on top of the controller/service method.

@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#groupId ,'groupd','delete')")

This will move all the authorization logic across all the different services into a single class.

Comment: My question was not only regarding security and authoritzation. I would like to know where to call these rather complicated logics that should be done on the DTO. Should I pass the DTO to the service layer and handle it there, or should we  do the job on the DTO in the controller layer and then pass the Entity to the service layer.

Comment: pre authorization and security is generally concerned as a cross cutting concern. Instead of writing those things in each and every service using the annotations above those things are moved away from actual business logic and are handled by spring layer.  Generally we use this annotations at the controller layer